# Hide JList within JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

When I try setting the `JList` visibility to `false` to hide the content, I discover that the list is not hidden entirly when I scroll down. I have tried `validate()` and `repaint()` of `JList`, `JScrollPane` and `JPanel` (`MainPanel`), but no changes, I have also tried this:

```
jScollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
    javax.swing.ScrollPaneCantants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

Also, no results. Some elements of the list remain visible if I scroll down the scroll bar.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov : My code is quite easy, When a button is clicked I have to hide the JList content, and my strategy is that I want to hide the JList and keep the JScollPane visible, that's all.

Comment: Also: set **Vertical** ScrollBarPolicy ... **HORIZONTAL** _SCROLLBAR_NEVER!

Comment: @Howard : Excuse me I haven't understood your comment

Comment: @Howard is highlighting the fact that `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER` is not a legal parameter to `setVerticalScrollBarPolicy()`; see the API for details.

Comment: _My code is quite easy_ the point is that it is not working as you expect it. So something is wrong, either your usage or your expectation. With very simple thingies like visibility, probably the former. The only way to discover such an error is to see your, well.. _code_ - best as an SSCCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least two ways to do that:

1. Remove the `JList` from the scrollpane: `scrollPane.setViewPortView(null);`
2. Set the model of the `JList` to an empty model: `list.setModel(new DefaultListModel());`

Another alternative is to change the scroll mode of the `JViewPort`:

```
scrollpane.getViewport().setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);
```

but of course this is not efficient at all. If you use that solution, when you make your component visible again, make sure to also properly reset the scroll mode to `BLIT_SCROLL_MODE` or `BACKINGSTORE_SCROLL_MODE` which are much more efficient.

Comment: hmm ... curious: what would the scrollMode help if the entire setup went wrong somehow?

Comment: @kleopatra sorry, don't understand what you imply by "entire setup went wrong"?

Comment: meant: in the OP's context ... though, concededly didn't try what would be expected on turning the view's visibility off. Anyway, how would the scrollMode help (really curious :-)?

Comment: @kleopatra it disables the usage of the backingStore image of the `JViewPort` which is otherwise not completely cleared when making the viewport view invisible.

Comment: ahh, I see - sweet hack (and you want to turn on the old mode later :-). Nudging to remove or strongly emphasize its hackyness - which I can't see any use-case for, as straightforward solutions are available.